# Dashboard example menu options vanish on small devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am super new to Bootstrap so please forgive me if I am just not getting it.
This is more of a design decision question than a technical question but I noticed in the bootstrap dashboard examples [Bootstrap 4 dashboard example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/dashboard/#) on a small device there is no way to navigate through the application as the left menu completely collapses and there is no + to expand the navbar. On the 3.3 version here: [Bootstrap 3.3 dashboard example](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/dashboard/) when the device is very small there is at least a + that allows you to expand the top navbar but still all of the options on the vertical menu on the left are completely lost.

Without the menu on the left it seems to me that the application would be unusable. Am I missing something?

Comment: If it's a design question then you've come to the wrong place. If it's anything related to programming, you've provided no code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In the example you are linking to, it seems that they've made a conscious choice to vanish navigation on small devices. Maybe because that dashboard is not designed to be used on small devices. (for example they use tables there etc.)

Comment: In other words, it is up to you to decide whether or not you want to vanish certain things on certain screens. It's not a limitation of Bootstrap, it's a feature that gives you the ability to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Default sidebar display in Bootstrap example is hidden `display: none;`
And for screen width > 768 px `@media (min-width: 768px) {}` they show this block.

You can do it yourself..
Here is original Bootstrap code:

```
/* Hide for mobile, show later */
.sidebar {
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 51px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  }
}
```